# Short story about an old rich man getting a younger body, but then the old body wants to be the one to live on

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I very vividly remember this story and I usually read pretty mainstream sci-fi stuff, so I immediately thought of some like, Asimov story. But it's probably from some obscure story collection I picked up.

So the story goes like this, an old rich guy goes for his usual treatment of getting a new young body and transferring his mind. The "old" body survives and they're allowed to live on in a sheltered place, where they are provided necessities to live a fulfilling life until they die. But of course, the old body still has a determined mind, which is deeply unsatisfied with its situation and ponders who has the right to live on and how to deal with his "brother". He then makes a plan to take, I think, a hostage (someone from the company), and asks the "new" body to come to talk to him, and they have an argument over who has the right to be called the true guy.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year or decade did you read this?

Comment: He's not growing potatoes, right?

Comment: This sounds a bit like [Fat Farm](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/57268/what-is-the-name-of-this-science-fiction-story-about-a-man-who-transfers-his-min) by Orson Scott Card, though the old bodies are treated as slave labour not cossetted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possibly "Shed Skin" by Robert J Sawyer:

This seems similar to the novel "Mindscan" by Robert J Sawyer, expanded from his earlier short story "Shed Skin"

The protagonist isn't old but is ill - the new body is an android, the old body gets sent to the moon, and then a cure is found... The old body wants it's life back

https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/robert-j-sawyer/mindscan/

Some info about the original short story:
https://www.sfwriter.com/oumi.htm

Comment: Yes I think this it it. The protagonist is *George Rathburn* and the home where the old bodies live is called *Paradise Valley*. George (the old George) takes one of the doctors at the home (*Lilly Ng*) hostage and threatens to kill her unless the new (android) body comes to Paradise Valley to talk to him.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's exactly it, I see my memory was a bit hazy but you were able to piece it together.